# On update current timestamp in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a table with columns (id, name,city, Current_TimeStamp) in Teradata 14.00.

If we update the name, the Current_Timestamp should be updated automatically, without having to specify it in the Update statement.
Any suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered using a trigger?

Comment: @Deepthy make this table as Temporal in Valid Time

Comment: How to use triggers for autoupdate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a trigger for on update timestamp in Teradata table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579648/how-to-create-a-trigger-for-on-update-timestamp-in-teradata-table)