# How to create a trigger for on update timestamp in Teradata table?

Tags: teradata

I am using Teradata 14.00

I have a table with columns (id, name,city,mytime) in Teradata 14.00.

If we update the name, the timestamp in 'mytime' column  should be updated automatically, without having to specify it in the Update statement.

How to use a trigger for this.

Any suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good article http://teradatafaqs.blogspot.in/p/tutorial.html for studying triggers.

For your ease here is the step by step creating of the trigger.

Sample table

```
Temp Table for your refernce :-
drop table DB_SOK.EMPLOYEE;
CREATE MULTISET TABLE DB_SOK.EMPLOYEE
( Employeeid INTEGER,
Employeename CHAR(30),
Salary INTEGER,
city varchar(100),
mytime timestamp(0));

insert into DB_SOK.EMPLOYEE values(1,'happy',100,'NYC',current_timestamp(0));

Select * from DB_SOK.EMPLOYEE;

Employeeid  Employeename    Salary  city    mytime
1               1           happy    100    NYC 11/7/2015 08:51:05
```

Then Create a Trigger for update for each row.

```
Replace  TRIGGER DB_SOK.EmpUpdate
AFTER UPDATE OF (Employeename) ON DB_SOK.EMPLOYEE
REFERENCING OLD ROW as EMPLOYEE_old_row
 NEW row  as EMPLOYEE_new_row
 FOR EACH ROW
update DB_SOK.EMPLOYEE
set mytime=current_timestamp(0)
```

Fire Update:-

```
update DB_SOK.EMPLOYEE
set  Employeename ='Hello Happy'
where Employeeid=1;
```

Select Data again to see data is update or not;

```
Select * from DB_SOK.EMPLOYEE;

Employeeid  Employeename    Salary  city    mytime
1   1   Hello Happy                     100 NYC 11/7/2015 09:02:23
```

Comment: Thank you so much  ..for the reply

Comment: command is working but all the values in 'mytime' column are updated to current_ timestamp

Comment: @Deepthy that is what it is defined in trigger ..you need to change as per your need.

Comment: how to specify the condition for updating only the required row's timestamp? any suggestions.

Comment: @Deepthy...you can use the when clause (optional one) after for. Read the above link for help.

Comment: Replace  TRIGGER DB_SOK.EmpUpdate  AFTER UPDATE OF (Employeename) ON DB_SOK.EMPLOYEE
REFERENCING OLD ROW as EMPLOYEE_old_row  NEW row  as EMPLOYEE_new_row
 FOR EACH ROW
update DB_SOK.EMPLOYEE
set mytime=current_timestamp(0) where id=EMPLOYEE_old_row.id;